# opencv findChessboardCorners cannot find corners

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, pose-estimation, corner-detection

I am using *Python3.10* and *Opencv 4.7*.

This is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('1_1691050309204.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (5, 6))
print(ret)
print(corners)
```

returns `False(ret)` and `None(corners)`.

What's wrong with the code or the image?

And attach the chessboard image.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add your complete code, just with the part you added is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it worked once I resized the image.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r'd:\chess.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]/2), int(img.shape[0]/2)))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (5, 6))

fnl = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (5, 6), corners, ret)
cv2.imshow("fnl", fnl)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: well what if the pattern is simply rotated by 90 degrees? it should still work. does the flipping of the grid dimensions really make a difference?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I give up on `findChessboardCorners`, while its analog `findChessboardCornersSB` seems to be a good choice.

According to the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gadc5bcb05cb21cf1e50963df26986d7c9), `findChessboardCornersSB` is more robust to all sort of noise, faster on larger images and is able to directly return the sub-pixel position of the internal chessboard corners.

So changing the code to this way, corners are returned:

```
flags = cv2.CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE + cv2.CALIB_CB_ACCURACY
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(gray, (5, 6), flags=flags)
```